# Magento Featured-Products extension debugging (shows all products instead of collection)

Tags: php, debugging, magento

I currently work on an online shop, running on Magento 1.4.1.1 (yeah.. I know..)
I have an extension installed to show some random featured products on the startpage. Here's the plug-in: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/featured-products-4605.html

The extension creates a new attribute "inchoo_featured_product" for products, wich makes it possible to choose a collection to show on the page. So the extension ran all the time (already a year) perfectly, but now it shows ALL products, not only selected. If I look up the product in Magento backend, I see that it is not checked to show up. (show on start page = no)

I couldn't figure out by myself how to fix the misbehaviour. How can I approach it to find out and fix it?
Reinstall didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1):

Ok people thank you for your suggestions. Now I found out what it was! It was just Magento indexing problem. the DB and all was working just fine, nothing changed but the server time limit was set to 30seconds so every time I re-indexed everything it was not complete and that caused the extension to break and behave randomly stupid :D
Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> So the extension ran all the time (already a year) perfectly

You must have changed something, software/websites don't break on their own. Try to think have you installed any new modules or made some other changes recently?

Comment: Hey, yeah I know, but I tried already to fix it by uninstalling an extension that I recently installed, but it seems not to fix it. Nothing changed besides this.. And I can't restore from backup couse it happened more than 2 weeks ago and backups are stored only for last two weeks.

Comment: That extension must have made a database change take a look at the 'sql' folder within that extension and see if you might be able to figure out what change it had done.

Comment: * software/websites don't break on their own  . Yes they do sometimes :> open source systems like wordpress, and magento can have plugins, conditionals, exceptions that can manifestate. Not saying this is the case.

Comment: Guilherme you make a valid point there are exceptions to this rule but almost always if something breaks it didn't happen on its own. It happens to me all the time the people tell me it just broke and when they step back and think they made a change which they thought was not relevant and that is what broke it.

Comment: Thank you Gershon Herczeg for that suggestion, I will look into sql changes tomorrow and try to find something. I'll post results here.

Comment: Some news here, today the extension just broke completely, a message "There are no products matching the selection" shows up. I did actually nothing it just happened today. I started to crawl through tehe code of the extension and found out, that if I comment out a line where $collection is being filtered: ->addAttributeToFilter('inchoo_featured_product', 1, 'left')
it works again with all products of course - no filtering. But it works at least like yesterday.

Comment: So my question is now - how can I check whether there is something wrong with the db or not? Ill try to make filtering with another attribute and let you know if it works with it.

Comment: Unfortunately it seem not to work at all. I found a desctiption how to use the filtering here:

Comment: http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/addattributetofilter-conditionals-in-magento.html
but if I use:
->addAttributeToFilter('id', array('lt' => 5));
As I understand, it should filter products with an ID under 5. And I have only 5 of them. But it just shows all products again. Any ideas?